# How can I split a string via first level square brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
key[type=order][0].item[id={getVal(obj[type=item][0].id)}]
```

and I want to split this string as like:

```
 [
     ['key', '[type=order]', '[0]'],
     ['item', '[id={getVal(obj[type=item][0].id)}]']
 ]
```

Firstly I split string via first level dot:

```
const str = 'key[type=order][0].item[id={getVal(obj[type=item][0].id)}]';
const arr = str.split(/\.(?![^[]*])/).filter(Boolean);
```

This generated array like this:

```
['key[type=order][0]', 'item[id={getVal(obj[type=item][0].id)}]']
```

And after that I want to split all array item via first level square bracket with:

```
arr.map(item => item.split(/(\[.+?\])/).filter(Boolean))
```

This generated array:

```
[
    ['key', '[type=order]', '[0]'],
    ['item', '[id={getVal(obj[type=item]', '[0]', '.id)}]']
]
```

I want to split items only first level square brackets not nested. How can I do this with regex in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it on your final split

```
arr.map(item => item.split(/(\[[^\]]+\(.*\).*\])|(\[.+?\])/).filter(Boolean))
```

Which generates the array:

```
[
    ['key', '[type=order]', '[0]'],
    ['item', '[id={getVal(obj[type=item][0].id)}]']
]
```

The regex is `/(\[[^\]]+\(.*\).*\])|(\[.+?\])/` and the first part of that looks for any square brackets with parentheses inside, and discounts any square brackets within those. After the `|` (or) your original regex runs!

**Update**

```
arr.map(item => item.split(/(\[[^\]]+\([^\)]*\)[^\]]*\])|(\[.+?\])/).filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it not work for this pattern "item[id={getVal('obj[type=product][0].id')}][0]". I want to split this as ["item", "[id={getVal('obj[type=product][0].id')}]", "[0]"] but this split as ["item", "[id={getVal('obj[type=product][0].id')}][0]"]

Comment: You can update the regex to `/(\[[^\]]+\([^\)]*\)[^\]]*\])|(\[.+?\])/` which should better suit the use case, as rather than matching everything with `.*` which is too greedy, I'm matching everything but not the closing parentheses / bracket e.g. `[^\)]*`.